# how to close canvas(which contain buttons) using button,in drracket,in it?

Tags: racket

```
 (define frame (new frame% [label "game"]
               [width 500] [height 500] [alignment '(center center)]))
(new button% [parent frame]
         [label "exit"]
         ; Callback procedure for a button click:
          [callback (    )])
```

> **I have tried this.**
>       **I couldn't get what to write in place of above space in parenthesis.**

Answer (score 0):

I hope this isn't homework...

```
#lang racket/gui
(define frame (new frame% [label "game"]
               [width 500] [height 500] [alignment '(center center)]))
(new button% [parent frame]
         [label "exit"]
         ; Callback procedure for a button click:
          [callback (lambda (d e) (send frame show #f))])
```

Because you've defined the frame already you can simply reference it in the callback for the button.

You can even go one step further and create a separate procedure and simply pass that procedure as the callback, as shown below:

```
#lang racket/gui
(define frame (new frame% [label "game"]
               [width 500] [height 500] [alignment '(center center)]))

(define thecallback
  (lambda (b e)
    (send frame show #f)))

(new button% [parent frame]
         [label "exit"]
         ; Callback procedure for a button click:
          [callback thecallback])
```

because this will allow you to have other things happen during the callback. Also, I personally like creating a separate callback like this because I think it makes the code easier to read.